# cargo-maven2-plugin debug timeout

Tags: maven, tomcat, cargo

I am attempting to debug a WAR in a cargo-maven2-plugin container.

```
<configuration>
                <type>standalone</type>
                <home>${project.build.directory}/tomcat8x/apache-tomcat-${tomcat.version}/container</home>
                <properties>
                    <cargo.hostname>${cargo.host}</cargo.hostname>
                    <cargo.servlet.port>${cargo.port}</cargo.servlet.port>
                    <!--<cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>-->
                    <cargo.start.jvmargs>
                    -Xdebug
                    -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
                    -Xnoagent
                    -Djava.compiler=NONE
                  </cargo.start.jvmargs>
                </properties>
```

Above is the debug section of the container...

I can connect to the socket and break at the correct point in my code but it is timing out after 6000ms and completing before I can step through the part I need to look into. Is there a way to prevent that?

StackTrace...

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timed out to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080 of 60000 ms
at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.timeout.TimeoutTimerTask.expire(TimeoutTimerTask.java:47) [async-http-client-1.9.30.jar:na]
at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.request.timeout.RequestTimeoutTimerTask.run(RequestTimeoutTimerTask.java:48) [async-http-client-1.9.30.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:556) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:632) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:369) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Comment: Can you update your question with maven console logs so we can see more details? What exactly is timing out?

Comment: My pleasure - added :)